# Azure functions is not loggin all the traces in AppInsights

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have an Azure Function App with multiples functions connected with Application Insights.

For some reason that I don't know sometimes, some requests and traces get lost and it's like they never happen, but I can see the data in our DB and also in others systems.

Here is a new function with just one call, in the azure function dashboard I can see the log:
[image]

But in Application Insights, when I try to search for the logs of the trace or the request, there is not info retrived.
[image]

This's not happening everytime, but there's not the first time I saw this issue. I can see the logs for others requests but I don't know why sometimes logs are lost.

Azure function info:

- Runtime Version: 3
- Stack: NodeJS

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the problem and can you repeatedly replicate missing entries. It would be good to see your code and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured sampling? This can appear as data loss.

You can control it as follows, [as per the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs#sampling):

```
const appInsights = require("applicationinsights");
appInsights.setup("<instrumentation_key>");
appInsights.defaultClient.config.samplingPercentage = 33; // 33% of all telemetry will be sent to Application Insights
appInsights.start();
```

Comment: I have configured AppInsghts to retain using ingestion sampling at 100%